# Trigger a function only once on completion of a celery task

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a function say `clear_cache`. I want to execute this function on completion of a celery task. I understand I can use [`on_success`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.on_success) for celery task but I don't want to execute the `clear_cache` function every time the task is completed. I want to execute it only once at a certain time.  And, I don't want to make `clear_cache` a celery task either, I want to keep it as a function only.

Is there any way that I can implement `on_success` functionality for [signature](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#signatures) or any other alternatives, please suggest.

Comment: Can't you simply call it (on some condition) inside that task before it returns?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But, I just wanted to know if there is way I can do it this way with out using any condition or flag in task. `on_success` seems a great way to handle this but just don't want to run `clear_cache` for every task. So, just want to know if I can add that functionality to a Signature.